# root interlacing condition for this problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider the quasi-polynomial
$$
F(z)=(a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0)e^{\tau z}+(b_2z^2+b_1z+b_0)\;,
$$
where $a_j,b_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. One can decompose $F(z)$ into even and odd order terms (denoted $F_e$ and $F_o$, respectively.):
$$
F(z)=F_e(z)+F_o(z)\;,
$$
where 
$$
\begin{array}{ccl}
F_e(z) &=& (a_2z^2+a_0)e^{\tau z}+(b_2z^2+b_0)\;,\\
F_o(z) &=& (a_3z^3+a_1z)e^{\tau z}+b_1z\;.
\end{array}
$$
The first question I have is whether $F(z)$ is an entire function of finite exponential type. This is critical in what I'm planning to do eventually. I recall that an entire function $F(z)$ is said to be of finite exponential type $\alpha$ if there exists an $A$ such that
$$
|F(z)|\leq Ae^{\alpha |z|}\;,~\mbox{with}~\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{+}~ \mbox{finite}\;.
$$
Can we establish this for the given $F(z)$?

Next, I have read about something termed a ``root interlacing condition'' before. If we suppose that the roots of $F_e$ and $F_o$ lie on the imaginary axis, what condition guarantees that such roots are interlacing? I need to understand the mathematical reasoning that leads to the condition.